# Hang heavy frameless mirror with broken mount

Tags: mounting, mirror

I have a heavy second hand mirror (100cm wide, 12.5kg) but the mounting bracket screws have pulled through the thin chipboard (5mm) backing piece. It is frameless with a decorative mirror edge.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how we could mount this mirror without using mirror clips?

I have considered

- gluing a new plywood back onto the mirror and sandwiching large washers between the new plywood and the old back that wire would attach to
- glue a french cleat on but was concerned about the size required for a heavy mirror and the safety factor

Does anyone have any other ideas or tips? Are mirror clips the best option (even if they will slightly ruin the effect)? thanks
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered moving the metal plate a bit to new holes, and using 4 screws each instead of two? You could add a compatible adhesive as well.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. I was concerned that new screws into 5mm chipboard would not hold 12.5kg. Do you think it would, if adhesive was added to the plate? In the original design, the screw head was actually sandwiched between the mirror and the backing (without a washer) and this is what has pulled through.